# Automate fetching BQ Dataset ACLs

Tags: bash, google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

For context, my team manages a Terraform mono-repo and GCP projects are managed within our repo. Datasets are structured in a yaml manner, i.e., within each GCP project folder there is a `datasets.yaml` that follows the structure:

```
datasets:
    - name: datasetA
      authorized_views: # list of auth views
      authorized_datasets: # list of auth datasets
    - name: datasetB
      ...
```

Since we've got some legacy projects, we wish to import datasets that live outside of TF into our config. So we added that feature, and now if we specify as well `import: true` the dataset is imported.
However, some of these legacy projects have a lot of datasets, and it would be nice to have a script that could write on this yaml - this is the challenge I'm facing.

My rationale is the following:

- Using bash, and given a `project_id` I want to retrieve from the BQ project all the dataset names and their ACLs (I'm only interested in authorised views and authorised datasets).
- Check against the existing `datasets.yaml` whether the dataset exists, if not add to the yaml and make sure to specify `import:true`. If it does exist, then we don't do anything.

Do you agree this would be the best approach?